# Python Selenium - Clicking Next Page

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently writing a python selenium script to take information of a website.

I have successfully got the data of page 1/100+ in the format I want. I unfortunately can’t get the program to run and collect all the information off the proceeding pages.

When I look at the web site [target](https://www.freshfields.com/en-gb/contacts/find-a-lawyer/) script, it shows me that the “Next” button is compiled like the below;

```
/body/div[@id='main-content']/div[@class='t6a-grid']/div[@class='mmargin-bottom-30']/div[@id='grid']/div[@class='row-margin-bottom-10']/div[@class='col-md-12 padding-left-0 padding-right-20']/ul[@class='pagination']/li[11]/a
```

Part of the script I have written is below. The "# this is navigate to next page element" in the script is the area that isn’t currently working.

```
def get_links(driver, target):
    # this is to collect links that associate with all the profiles present in Freshfields website

    driver.get(target)
    # get links associated to profiles on result page
    list_links = [] 
    while True:
        list_ppl_link =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class=" mix item col-xs-6 col-sm-4"]')      
        for item in list_ppl_link:
            emp_name_obj = item.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
            emp_name = emp_name_obj.text
            emp_link = emp_name_obj.get_attribute('href')
            list_links.append({'emp_name':emp_name, 'emp_link':emp_link})
        try:
            # this is navigate to next page
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="pagination"]/li').click()
            time.sleep(1)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
    return list_links
```

Please could somebody help me to understand how I can loop through the pages and collect the 1,960 records?

Comment: Work a little bit more on a formatting of your question, beacuase it's not clear. I can't see antything what is in "bold italic".

Comment: Hi. Good point. I have updated the question now to identify the area not working which is "# this is navigate to next page element" in the script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using something like below:

```
list_ppl_link =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class=" mix item col-xs-6 col-sm-4"]') 
    i=1     
    for item in list_ppl_link:
        i=i+1
        emp_name_obj = item.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        emp_name = emp_name_obj.text
        emp_link = emp_name_obj.get_attribute('href')
        list_links.append({'emp_name':emp_name, 'emp_link':emp_link})
    try:
        # this is navigate to next page
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="pagination"]//li/a[contains(text(),"' + str(i) +'")').click()
        time.sleep(1)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have tried that method and I get the following error message "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects". Please could you advise?

Comment: okay so you have to convert your  `i ` to string using `str(i)` ;i've updated the code.

Comment: Just next to any answers on SO there will be tick mark sign, clicking that would make an answer as accepted.