# Python Web Scrape Multiple Pages only one Static Link

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract data from the following website: https://www.centris.ca/en/multi-family-properties~for-sale~montreal-island?view=List .
While I have been able to get the data I was looking for from the first page, I am struggling to create a loop for all the pages, as it looks like there is no mention of "pages" that I could leverage in the link .
Instead it seems like the link stays the same whatever the page you are moving to.

Your help would be much appreciated :)
Thanks !

Here is the code I have so far, which seems to work for extracting the data on one page, but I am trying to find a way to loop it to automate the data loading after clicking on "Next Page":

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.centris.ca/en/multi-family-properties~for-sale~montreal-island?view=List'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# grabs each product
descriptions = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"description"})

filename = "houses-v2.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "pgr, price\n"

f.write(headers)

for description in descriptions:
# description = descriptions[0]

pgr = description.p.span.span.text.strip()

price_description = description.findAll("p", {"class":"price"})
price = price_description[0].text.strip()

print(pgr)
print(price)

f.write(pgr.replace(",", "") + ',' + price.replace(",", "") + '\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have just added the code I have written so far.

Comment: Well, the pages come from a JSON POST request to 'https://www.centris.ca/Mvc/Property/GetInscriptions'. If you open up dev-tools in Chrome you can see it in the network-tab if you click on next page.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that and for your reply Jorden. I am just getting started with web scrapping, so I am not very comfortable yet with these types of requests. Does that mean that there is no way to automatically loop the pagination ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have been successful with your **scraping** but I've been looking into this particular case.

You will have to use the `selenium` package, you can install it with pip (`pip install selenium`) or conda (`conda install selenium`)

This package is for web browser automation. More info [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

You will be able to open a session similar to get request.
Then virtually click on the next page button. From there you should be able to get data from the other pages. I also recommend you to rewrite the `BeautifulSoup` part in `Selenium` for code consistency.

You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886907/python-selenium-clicking-next-page)!
The interesting part is :

```
# this is navigate to next page
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="pagination"]/li').click()
```

Where "driver" is your session, "find_element_by_xpath" will be like "find" and "find_all" from `BeautifulSoup` and the "click" function will let you activate the html element. The only thing left is to find the html element linked with the next page button!

Keep me posted!